# Why is the Navigation Bar on GitHub.com Black when I am Signed In?

Tags: github

Recently, the navigation bar of [GitHub.com](https://github.com) became black for me, but only when I am signed in.

*The below screenshot demonstrates what it looks like when I am signed in.*

[image: This screenshot demonstrates what it looks like when I am signed in.]

*The below screenshot demonstrates what it looks like when I am signed out.*

[image: This screenshot demonstrates what it looks like when I am signed out.]

Previously, the color of the navigation bar was the same (white) regardless of whether I am signed out or signed in.

In addition, according to the latest screenshot from their [Blog on February 1, 2017](https://github.com/blog/2311-see-your-project-s-history-with-the-activity-view), the navigation bar is white for them.

*The below screenshot is taken from GitHub's Blog on February 1, 2017.*

[image: Screenshot from GitHub's Blog on February 1, 2017.]

**So my question is, why is my navigation bar black only when I am signed in to GitHub.com, and how can I revert it back to being the same color as when I am signed out?**

Comment: Why? Because GitHub changed it. You'll need to ask them "why".

Comment: @ale Ah, I see. The inconsistency between being logged in vs logged out and their blog still showing the white navigation bar had me confused, and led me to believe it was something that I had done. Since that is not the case, if you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a recent feature/change. Initially I thought it's because of the [Black History Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_History_Month) which is celebrated in February in Canada and USA.

It's a long term change. This is what they replied me:

> There aren't currently plans to revert this change (it isn't for Black History month), but I'll definitely pass your comments on to our design team for their consideration :)

So, it's just a design change. There are ways to remove it, just by removing the `header-dark` class or installing an extension which does that.